# Multi broker cluster

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using this [tutorial](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_multibroker) for multibroker kafka cluster.
I established three brokers:

- localhost:9092
- localhost:9093
- localhost:9094

And used this command: `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic my-replicated-topic`

As far as I understand if one of my broker dies the other will still running and processing messages.

The problem is that if I kill `9092` I cannot use this command:
`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic`

I know that port is killed, but - how to pass generic bootstrap-server to get it running? What am I missing?

**EDIT1:**

After

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic

it gives me message:

> WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-82352] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)`

And console stops. No messages read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list of brokers in `bootstrap-server`:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic
```

Comment: Not sure why you added the [tag:spring-kafka] tag; this question has nothing to do with Spring. That said, I just tested it and it works fine for me (using kafka 0.11). I only have one broker but `$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9998,localhost:9092,localhost:9999 --topic testIn --from-beginning` connected to 9092 ok. The INFO log on the console shows they were correctly parsed into a list: `bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9998, localhost:9092, localhost:9999]`. And `WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established` (and -3), and it displayed the records ok.

Comment: I wanted to add some java code which is related, but after that I noticed that I can do same with just scripts. I removed tag.

Comment: It seems that my kafka has some problem with choosing leader. I have two brokes available but leader is `-1`

Comment: FYI. I added 2 more brokers and had a similar problem. The client didn't fail over. I blew away the kafka logs and zookeeper data and restarted the brokers and all started working ok.